# Rails how to update records where column is nil for all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to set udtraekkes (datetime) to NULL for all those records where udtraekkesinfo is NOT equal NULL or NIL. My model name is Konkurrencer.

How do I update alle the konkurrencers records in the rails console?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `update_all` method. [Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class)

Comment: I have tried: Konkurrencer.update_all("udtraekkes = NULL", :udtraekkesinfo => not_eq(nil) )
NoMethodError: undefined method `not_eq' for main:Object

Comment: Konkurrencer.update_all("udtraekkes = NULL", "udtraekkesinfo <> 0") - try this

Comment: It should be where udtraekkes is not equal NIL, because all records are all not NULL.

Comment: What does it mean - NIL (in this case)?

Comment: It means where udtraekkesinfo.nil? is not true.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9267/discussion-between-railscard-and-rails-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

> Konkurrencer.update_all({udtraekkes: nil}, "udtraekkesinfo IS NOT NULL")

Comment: Just set all records to udtraekkes NULL with your quiry :(

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.0.13,
 I tested with this syntax might it would do same for you in rails 3.

```
Model.where(conditions).update_all(:column_name=> nil)
where conditions are filtered condition to fetch the each record and update_all will operate on those record, you can update one or more column based on your requirement.
```

for your requirement code would be.

```
Konkurrencer.where(:udtraekkes=> nil).update_all(:udtraekkes=> nil)
```